Simple indicator in Backtrader only calculates correctly for the first stock
There's a log return indicator. I added multiple stocks into Cerebro.
class LogReturn(bt.Indicator):

    lines = ("log_return",)

    def __init__(self, x):

        self.x = x
        self.addminperiod(2)

    def next(self):

        self.lines.log_return[0] = np.log(self.x[0]) - np.log(self.x[-1])

class Test(bt.Strategy):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.log_return = [LogReturn(x = d.close) for d in self.datas]

    def next(self):

        all_returns = [str(round(self.log_return[i].lines.log_return[0], 3)) for i in range(3)]

        print(" ".join(all_returns))

It prints:
-0.003 0.017 0.007
-0.014 0.017 0.007
0.01 0.017 0.007
0.003 0.017 0.007
-0.015 0.017 0.007
0.0 0.017 0.007
0.008 0.017 0.007
0.011 0.017 0.007
0.023 0.017 0.007
0.014 0.017 0.007
-0.005 0.017 0.007
-0.014 0.017 0.007

Each column is a return for a stock, as you can see only the first column calculates correctly. All other columns are constant.
I've check the data are correct.
In LogReturn.next, for the first stock, self.x[0] access the proper value. For the rest stocks, self.x[0] always give the first value in self.x like a numpy array.

How to calculate the indicators for each stock correctly?
